# Firebase database doesnt work after publishing app to play store

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-keystore

I have a problem. I've coded app in android studio. After publishing app to play store, firebase database doesn't work at all. I added SHA1 key to firebase console project settings, what can be wrong?

[image: Firebase console screenshot]

Any help appreciated.

I took SHA1 key from here:

[image: SHA1 key screenshot]

Comment: firebase database doesn't require SHA1 key to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, it's very weird though. The variables in class where i stored all the data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWVX1.png) were not private. After i add private modifier to all variables problem was solved [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xgcy.png)

Answer (score 1):

there different SHA1 keys for debug and release version you are most likely using debug SHA1 key

generate relase SHA1 key using below code and add it to console firebase will work

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

[tutorial here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would be aware of that release APK and debug APK has different SHA1 and different API keys for `google services`. So you need to add both of them on Firebase inside your Project Setting. After doing this you need to redownload the google-services.json file and put it in your project at the right palce. Create a fresh release build with your keystore and publish you app on Google Play store.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi Alex, could you please help this one? it seems similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72445017/firebase-cloud-messaging-is-not-working-after-publishing-android-app-in-play-sto

Comment: @Alexa289 I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.

Answer (score 0):

> You will need to register the **SHA-1** or **SHA-256** keys of your
>   **RELEASE-APK** which is different from the **DEBUG-APK** on your firebase project settings using => `add finger print` option.

### DEBUG APK & HOW TO GENERATE DEBUG - SHA FINGERPRINT KEYS

- **Debug keystore** is generated by default when you either run your app using the **RUN** button in Android Studio or when you **build a debug apk**.
- **Debug-keystore** uses **android** both as the **keystore** name and the **alias** name by default in order to generate the SHA keys.
- And the location of the debug-keystore is **C:\Users\USERNAME\ .android** by default.
- So, you simply need open **CMD** and point it to `C:\Program Files\Java\bin` directory and use this command to generate the debug SHA fingerprint ( if you want to generate the keys to a txt file i.e. in **D:** directory and in a text file called **sha.txt** add this to the end of the command below:  `> D:\sha.txt:`  )

> keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias
>   androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

### RELEASE APK & HOW TO GENERATE RELEASE-SHA FINGERPRINT KEYS

- Release keystore is generated when you generate a release apk using `Build => Generate signed Apk/Bundle` option in Android Studio.
- When you do so for the first time you are asked to create a new keystore, where you specify many details most notably: **Keystore Path & Name**, **Password**, **Alias** and **Password** (for key).
- From the above mentioned parameters we will need **Keystore Path & Name** and **Alias** for the command, plus the **keystore password** which is asked for, after the command is executed.
- Now execute the following command keeping the above parameters in view.
- ( if you want to generate the keys to a txt file i.e. in **D:** directory and in a text file called **sha.txt** add this to the end of the command below:  `> D:\sha.txt:`  )

> ```
> keytool -list -v -keystore <keystore_path\your_keystore_name> -alias <your_alias_name>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For those who still facing similar problem.

Things to consider as per [firebase checklist](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/launch-checklist)

1. Add your app release SHA1 fingerprint to firebase project settings for Authentication
2. Configure your pro guard rules when using Firebase Realtime Database in your app along with ProGuard, you need to consider how your model objects will be serialized and deserialized after obfuscation. If you use `DataSnapshot.getValue(Class)` or `DatabaseReference.setValue(Object)` to read and write data, you will need to add rules to the proguard-rules.pro file:

## Add this global rule

```
-keepattributes Signature

# This rule will properly ProGuard all the model classes in
# the package com.yourcompany.models. Modify to fit the structure
# of your app.
-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** {
  *;
}
```